# progress template in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my web application i am uploading a video file. While uploading i want to give message to user wait video uploading can i use UpdateProgress can u give me a simple example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi there here is a small example how you display a updateprogress on a background job:

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
    
    
    
        UpdateProgress control
    
    
        
            
            
                
                    Loading...

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```